# Sorting Data with awk or Perl

Tags: perl, unit-testing, sorting, unix, awk

I have a text file with data like:

```
# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.013578591, CID: 1004592976
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3

# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.013580787, CID: 1004592977
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3
Option1:34
Option5:98
```

One Data Unit starts from '#' til the next '#'. Like from the above sample one data unit is:

```
# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.013580787, CID: 1004592977
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3
```

Now I have to sort this data on the basis of DTG. (e.g 20140109183524.013580787 as given in the second data unit).

The output file would have the same data but sorted on the basis of DTG value (which is actually date and time).

The other data units are unimportant as far as sorting of data is concerned.

The actual input file would contain thousands of such entries. 
What would be the fastest way to achieve a sorted data? Speed is actually important in achieving the required result.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried; are there errors or do you need simple optimization?

Comment: How do you want the sorting based on DTG to be done? For example for `20140109183524.013580787`: Should the whole number be used without the dot, like `20140109183524013580787` and then do an ascending numerical sort on this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like (I added some records for testing):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use v5.16;
my (%data,$DTG);
while(<DATA>) {
  if(/^#.*?DTG:\s(.*?),/) {
     $DTG = $1;
       }
  if($DTG) {
      $data{$DTG} .= $_;
     }
   }
 for my $d (sort keys %data) {
    print $data{$d};
  }


__DATA__
# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.013578591, CID: 1004592976
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3

# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.013580787, CID: 1004592977
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3
Option1:34
Option5:98

# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.013580900, CID: 1004592977
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3
Option1:34
Option5:198
# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.000580787, CID: 1004592977
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3
Option1:34
Option5:298
```

Or if you prefer a oneliner:

```
perl -wlne 'if(/^#.*?DTG:\s(.*?),/) {$DTG = $1;} if($DTG) {$data{$DTG} .= $_."\n"} END {for(sort keys %data) {print $data{$_},"\n"}}' datafile.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not so familiar with Perl, what is the reason for using version 5.16?

Comment: Not really needed for this solution, but its part of my template when I create a new script. Usually need it if using features added in modern perl versions.

Comment: Ok :) I see, I have only version 5.14.2 on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: I tried to test your code and changed to `use v5.14` and run it as `perl s.perl file` and got error: `Name "main::DATA" used only once: possible typo at s.perl line 6`

Comment: @HåkonHægland ah yes this is a recent feature, if really curious you can remove that part of the script __ DATA __ and all the lines below, change this line <DATA> to <> and call the script with a data file like `perl scriptname.pl datafile`

Comment: Thanks, the one liner worked like a charm. One thing, There is an empty line after every record, but sorting removes that. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @user3195304 yes I just did an edit on it, try it now. Is it sorting accurately for you?

Comment: Sorry, I did not test your oneliner, it works well (it does lexical sorting though). It it is only a little bit slower than my solution.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way, assuming you have a blank line between records as shown in your sample input:

```
awk -v RS= '{gsub(/a/,"aA"); gsub(/\n/,"aB"); print $5, $0}' file |
sort |
awk -v ORS='\n\n' '{sub(/[^ ]+ /,""); gsub(/aB/,"\n"); gsub(/aA/,"a")}1'
```

The above compresses each record onto a single line by converting all "a"s to "aA" and then "\n"s to "aB" (so you KNOW later when converting back that an "aB" in the input can only have come from this second gsub() since all original "aB"s had been converted to "aAB"s by the first gsub()), prepends the DTG value, sorts on that, and then reverses the process.

I timed this on a file with 100,000 records (the sample 2 you posted repeated 50,000 times) and it took just a bit under 7 seconds to run:

```
real    0m6.930s
user    0m6.722s
sys     0m0.388s
```

To help @Jotne see what happens when running is script on cygwin with bash 4.1.11(2), perl 5.14.4, here's what happens for me the 2 versions of the script, the 2nd with the modified print statement:

```
$ cat file
# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.013578591, CID: 1004592976
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3

# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.013580787, CID: 1004592977
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3
Option1:34
Option5:98
```

#

```
$ printf "20140109183524.013580787\n20140109183524.013578591\n" | sort
20140109183524.013578591
20140109183524.013580787

$ printf "20140109183524.013580787\n20140109183524.013578591\n" | sort -n
20140109183524.013578591
20140109183524.013580787
```

#

```
$ cat script1.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $dtg;
my %data;

while (<>) {
    if (/^#.*?DTG: ([\d.]+)/) {
        $dtg = $+;
    }
    $data{$dtg} .= $_;
}

print @data{sort keys %data};
```

#

```
$ cat script2.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $dtg;
my %data;

while (<>) {
    if (/^#.*?DTG: ([\d.]+)/) {
        $dtg = $+;
    }
    $data{$dtg} .= $_;
}

print @data{sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data};
```

#

```
$ perl script1.pl < file
# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.013578591, CID: 1004592976
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3

# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.013580787, CID: 1004592977
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3
Option1:34
Option5:98
```

#

```
$ perl script2.pl < file
# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.013580787, CID: 1004592977
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3
Option1:34
Option5:98
# Pri: Rest, DTG: 20140109183524.013578591, CID: 1004592976
dn: op=applV,uid=2256c1e8-1166-46e4-a3a9-9fbe27694e12,Name=sub,loc=Ph,o=s,o=s.com
action: add
Class: c-subSpecData
Option3: applView
Option2: 3
```

As you can see the second version of the perl script prints the records in the opposite order from desired whether it's alphabetic or numerical sorting.

Comment: I tested the speed for this on 16 Mb random file with 80000 records: It seems to be about 4 times as slow as `janos` solution.. @janos runs at 0.063 secs, and this used 2.43 secs .

Comment: I found a similar time difference when I ran janos' solution on my 100K sample input file (his ran in 1.3 secs vs my 6.9 secs) BUT janos' output was sorted incorrectly when using his "corrected" sorting print statement. His original one seemed to work fine though, so I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Yes the new version of @janos did not work for me either..

Comment: Personally, even if it does take 4 secs longer for a 100K file, I like my `awk | sort | awk` solution because every individual step is simple, it follows the UNIX idiom of piping between the best tools for the job, and at it's core it uses the primary UNIX tool created for the primary job, i.e. `sort` for sorting, so you know that's going to be able to concisely and robustly do whatever kind of sort is required.

Comment: +1 I like your solution because it's *clever*. But cleverness makes it a bit hacky, in contrast with a straightforward perl script. I agree with the beauty of piping, but since the OP asked specifically for speed, an `awk | sort | awk` solution is just inevitably lossy. I don't know if the difference is really significant though.

Answer (score 1):

In Gnu Awk version 4.1 you can use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to sort, like

```
gawk -f s.awk file
```

where `s.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {RS="^$"}
{
    n=split($0,a,/# Pri: [^0-9]* DTG: [0-9]*\.[0-9]*/,s)
    top=s[0] a[1]
    for (i=1;i<n; i++) {
        match(s[i],/DTG: ([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)/,c)
        b[(c[1] c[2])]=s[i] a[i+1]
    }
}


END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
    printf "%s%s", s[0], a[1]
    for (i in b)
        printf "%s", b[i]
    printf "%s", s[n]
}
```

**Update**

Seems that this method was slowed down by the `match()` function.
Here is a version that is approximately 2.5 times faster:

```
BEGIN {RS="^$"}
{
    n=split($0,a,/# Pri: [^0-9]* DTG: [0-9]*\.[0-9]*/,s)
    top=s[0] a[1]
    for (i=1;i<n; i++) {
        ind=index(s[i],"DTG:")
        c=substr(s[i],ind+5)
        ind=index(c,".")
        c=substr(c,1,ind-1) substr(c,ind+1)
        b[c]=s[i] a[i+1]
    }
}


END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
    printf "%s%s", s[0], a[1]
    for (i in b)
        printf "%s", b[i]
    printf "%s", s[n]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $dtg;
my %data;

while (<>) {
    if (/^#.*?DTG: ([\d.]+)/) {
        $dtg = $+;
    }
    $data{$dtg} .= $_;
}

print @data{sort keys %data};
```

If you save this script in `script.pl`, then you can use it like this:

```
perl script.pl < data.txt
```

However, when sorting the DTG values on the last line, the `sort` function treats the values as strings, sorting them alphabetically, as [@hakon-haegland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173773/hakon-haegland) pointed out in his comment. As a consequence, a value like `1001` would incorrectly come before `110`, for example.

If you want to enforce sorting numerically, *you can try this*:

```
print @data{sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data};
```

However, this doesn't work well with numbers with too many digits, such as the ones in the OP's example, and the behavior may also depend on the version of Perl. As of perl 5.12.4, this technique seems to work reliably with numbers with less than 16 digits.

Comment: +1 Nice one! Currently this is about 3 times faster than my solution, but it does a different sorting. It sorts based on string value, so for example the values `1,110,1001` it sorts as `1,1001,110`..

Comment: @HåkonHægland well spotted! I added a fix for that.

Comment: I cannot get your improved version to work, it seems to have the similar problems as @Kenosis solution had (it does not sort correctly) before he fixed it..

Comment: @HåkonHægland thanks for your vigilance, but it still works for me :s Tested in osx and debian, with or without numeric sort

Comment: janos - it sorts incorrectly for me on cygwin (bash 4.1.11(2), perl 5.14.4) with your modified print. The original one seem to work fine.

Comment: @EdMorton Weird. It works for me in Git Bash (bash 3.1, perl 5.8.8). When you say it doesn't work, you mean the ordering is incorrect, or something else?

Comment: I mean the ordering is incorrect. I just updated my answer to show you your 2 perl script versions running on a sample input file.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, you're right, I overlooked something earlier. It doesn't work as advertised in my Git Bash, nor in an older Linux I have here. I will check again at home but I suspect I probably overlooked there too, and this never really worked. :(

Comment: @EdMorton ok I'm NOT going insane. It doesn't work for *long* numbers like the ones used in the OP, but it should work with shorter ones, like the examples Hakon gave. In any case, it's a moot point, as I have a feeling the OP has data with uniform format where alphabetic comparison is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$/="#"; # to read the record from # to # as a single line
open "FH" , "< input.txt " ;
my @data = <FH> ;
chomp(@data);
my %data ;

foreach my $line ( @data )
{
  $line =~ /DTG:\s*(.*?),/;
chomp($1);
  $data{$1}=$line ;
}


foreach ( sort { $a <=> $b }(keys %data ) )
{
    print "$data{$_} \n";
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a very fast script.. What is the purpose of adding the text `"hi "`?

Comment: lol..! well its just a magic word which brings people together :P .. Sorry it was just what I used to test the o/p .

Comment: I see :) Your code is still fast, but it modifies the original records of the file, such that the sorted records miss the `#` sign from the original records, in addition the sorting is done lexiacally and not numerically..

Comment: Well yeah that was the default which the sort command uses and moreover "#" is being removed since here we are  considering "#" as a delimetre while reading the input $/='#'

Answer (score 0):

This option sets reading the file in paragraph mode (`local $/ = '';`), to read it in chunks, as this avoids the time it takes to concatenate 'record' lines.  It also doesn't assume that the date/time stamps are all unique, so it creates a hash of arrays (HoA) for the records:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
local $/ = '';

while (<>) {
    s/\s+$//;
    push @{ $hash{$1} }, $_ if /DTG:\s+([^,]+?),/;
}

for my $key ( sort timeStamp keys %hash ) {
    print $_, "\n\n" for @{ $hash{$key} };
}

sub timeStamp{
    my @a = split /\./, $a;
    my @b = split /\./, $b;
    return $a[0]  <=> $b[0] || $a[1]  <=> $b[1]
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your script, it is very fast, but somehow it does not sort correctly.. Maybe I did some mistake when I run it? I am not so familiar with perl yet :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland - What were the `sort` results?  The records `sort`ed numerically OK using an expanded dataset.  Also, made a minor edit: removed trailing whitespaces from each record, so `print`ing is consistent.

Comment: Still not sorting correctly for me: Try it on this file : http://pastebin.com/5kurgq3L

Comment: Here are the first 100 lines of the sorted result for a 80000 record file with random DTG's: http://pastebin.com/H4wNmDe3 . As you see the results looks strange..

Comment: @HåkonHægland - Appreciate the data.  Fixed.

Comment: Yes it works now, but it seems to be much slower now :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland - Using a lexical sort for the keys doesn't work for the reason you mentioned in an earlier comment.  A simple numeric sort also doesn't work, thus the `sub`.  Tried it with 80k records and it handled the task rather quickly.